# append value into dropdown-list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, multiple-select

i'm using the source code for multiple selection

[Dropdown check-list](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/)

Since, the example has been shown for the static values, i have edited as per my requirement, And i was trying to populate the values of the dropdown list using database, which means dynamically populating the values into the dropdown-list. But, i'm failed to do. Please help me. The dropdown list will be populated as per the option selected from the first dropdown

```
<select id="design" onmouseup="showOfficer()" >
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
 </select>

<select id="officers" class="officers" multiple="multiple"><div id="show_officer"></div></select>
```

my **javascript**

```
<script language="javascript" >
function showOfficer(){
                        document.getElementById("msg4").style.display="block";
                       $.ajax({
                            url: 'getValues.jsp',
                            data: 'design_id='+ $('#design').val(),
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(msg){document.getElementById("show_officer").innerHTML=msg;
                                document.getElementById("msg4").style.display="none";
                            }});
                    }
</script>
```

**getValues.jsp**

```
<%@include file="../dbconfig.jsp" %><%
String design=request.getParameter("design_id");
 String buffer="";
 try{
     int count=0;
 ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT OFFICER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME FROM OFFICER WHERE STATUS_TYPE='UNASSIGN' AND DESIGN_ID='"+design+"'");//
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(1)+"</option>";
   count++;
   }
 if(count==0)
     {
  buffer=buffer+"<option value='ERROR'>OFFICERS ASSIGNED ALREADY</option>";
 }
 }
 catch(Exception e){
    buffer=buffer+"<option value='ERROR'>OFFICERS ASSIGNED ALREADY</option>"+e;
 }
 buffer=buffer+"";
 //out.print(buffer);
 response.getWriter().print(buffer);
 %>
```

Please help me !!

Comment: I couldn't be sure what you to achieve clearly, but I think you want to keep "Dropdown Check List" after the new <option> tags come from server. Putting $("#officers").dropdownchecklist(); into ajax's success function may work. Also, interesting use of jQuery.

Comment: @gasoved, function will be called, when any value selected from the first dropdown-list, and the value of the second dropdown list dynamically change as per the value selected from the first dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
success: function(html){
    $("#msg4").hide();
    $("#officers").html(html);
    $("#officers").dropdownchecklist();
}
```

replace your success function with this and take that `div` out of your `select`.

If you're loading jQuery why don't you use it for more than just the ajax call?

remove the onmouseup, and try this:

```
$('#design').mouseup(function(){
    $("msg4").show();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'getValues.jsp',
            data: 'design_id='+ $('#design').val(),
            type: 'post',
            success: function(html){
                $("#msg4").hide();
                $("#officers").dropdownchecklist("destroy");
                $("#officers").html(html);
                $("#officers").dropdownchecklist();
            }
           });
});
```

Comment: but, if i replace onmouseup with the onchange, then it will create problem, when combobox will have only one item. On that case, it combo-box value won't change and then function can't be trigger.

Comment: thanks, this what i'm looking for, but the problem is, it's just appending the new dropdownlist. I mean, when i'm selecting value from the first dropdown list, then retreive dropdown append to the current dropdown, which means now i've two dropdown with same name and element. what to do now...??

Comment: @sql_query you have to send "destroy" to the dropdownchecklist first, I've updated my code.